# Update one field of a custom metadata from excel sheet

Tags: update, custom-metadata, excel

I have a custom metadata called **Animal__mdt** with one field called **Color** (Among other fields). I have the new values of Color in an excel sheet. There is a 1:1 relationship between the **Name field** of the Animal and the **Color**.

Can I just massively update one field with the excel sheet using the names and the colors of the animals??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Custom Metadata Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_dataloader.htm&type=5) you can use.

It would require you to deploy the above into your org and to follow the steps below:

> The custom metadata loader lets you load or update up to 200 records
>   with a single call.
>
> 1. Download the tool from GitHub and deploy the package to your org via
>      Workbench. Create the .zip file from the contents of the
>      custom_md_loader directory instead of zipping up the directory
>      itself.
> 2. Create a .csv file with a header that contains the custom metadata
>      type’s field API names. Either the Label or the Developer Name field
>      is required. See sample.csv in your download for an example. If your
>      org is namespaced, include the namespace prefix in your header. To
>      update an existing custom metadata record, use the Label or
>      Developer Name field to identify it.
> 3. From Setup, assign the Custom Metadata Loader permission set to the
>      appropriate users, including yourself.
> 4. From the App Picker, select Custom Metadata Loader.
> 5. Click the Custom Metadata Loader tab. If you haven’t already done
>      so, the app prompts you to configure your Remote Site Settings.
> 6. Upload your .csv file and select the corresponding custom metadata
>      type.
> 7. Click Create/Update custom metadata to bulk-load the records from
>      the .csv file or update existing records. If the file has duplicate
>      Label or Developer Name entries, the last entry becomes the new or
>      updated record.